# Deploy a Node.js app with a node-jdbc module to Bluemix

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to push a Node.js app with a node-jdbc module to Bluemix. This node-jdbc module requires JDK to be installed. Is there a way to push a Node.js app and also install JDK in the same runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I used to deploy a Bluemix Node.js application with `node-jdbc` dependency:

1) Download a JDK package for Linux x64 (compatible with Cloud Foundry stack)

2) Install/unzip the JDK package in the root's project directory, my directory was something like this (`jdk1.7.0_79` is the new directory I added):

```
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 adasilva  staff    436 Jan 24 18:21 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  15 adasilva  staff    510 Apr 10  2015 jdk1.7.0_79
-rw-r--r--@  1 adasilva  staff     72 Jan 27 15:27 manifest.yml
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 adasilva  staff    327 Jan 27 21:21 package.json
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 adasilva  staff   4412 Jan 24 18:21 server.js
```

3) Now, for the buildpack to detect the Java I had to set the following environment variable:

```
cf set-env your-app-name JAVA_HOME /tmp/staged/app/jdk1.7.0_79
```

After deployment the app directory will actually be at `/home/vcap/app`, but the compilation is done at staging so the directory is different

4) For runtime the application needs Java libraries, so I needed to also set another environment variable:

```
cf set-env your-app-name LD_LIBRARY_PATH /home/vcap/app/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/amd64:/home/vcap/app/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/amd64/server
```

Note that now I used the `/home/vcap/app` since runtime will be after app is deployed.

5) Run `cf restage` and `cf push` again to redeploy application.